# Is there any kind of SVM or other linear models can be applied to such scenery？

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, linear-model, unbalanced-classes

Consider that I have only several positive samples, say 4 or 5, and a big amount of negative samples. I want to find a hyperline can exactly seperate the positive samples and negative samples if the training data is linear separable and if it is not, I want a hyperline that mis-separate the training data as little as possible. Only negative samples are allowed to be mis-separated, which means all positive samples should be in the same side of the hyperline.
One thing to notice, we only consider linear models, which means we don't utlize any non-linear methods such us kernel methods.
Still, there is a close-world assumption, which indicates that we will not meet any new sample besides training samples.

Comment: Just use standard linear SVM with weighted cost function such as weight 100 for positive samples and weight 0.1 for negative samples.

Comment: @NikolasRieble Thanks! I've considered about that, but standerd linear SVM may not satisfy 'mis-separate the samples as little as possible' since it tries to maximize the gap while we don't really care about the gap.

Comment: @NikolasRieble Maybe I could just remove the structure risk in standard SVM

Comment: I do not understand - if you do not care about the gap, you might as well use linear SVM as well. The loss function of SVM is linear seperation. That is what is beeing optimized. I suggest: Try linear svm with weigthed cost function - plot the results - post them here. Then we can discuss possible further improvements etc.